# How to compute a per-class parameter from a mini-batch in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am starting to learn TensorFlow and I have a seemingly simple modeling question. Suppose I have a C-class problem and data arrives into TensorFlow in mini-batches containing B samples each. Each sample x is a D-dimensional vector that comes with its label y (non-negative integer between 0 and C-1). I want to estimate a class-specific parameter (for example the sample mean) for each class. The estimation takes place after each sample independently undergoes a TensorFlow-defined transformation pipeline. The per-class parameter/sample-mean is then utilized in the computation of other tensors.

Intuitively, I would group the samples in each mini-batch by label, sum-combine them, and add the total of each label group to the corresponding class parameter, with appropriate normalization.

How can I implement such a simple procedure (group by label, perform a per-group operation, then use the labels as indices for writing into a tensor) or an equivalent one, using TensorFlow? What TensorFlow operations do I need to learn about to achieve this? Is it advisable to do it outside TensorFlow?

Comment: Your question is pretty generic but it seems like it would be super simple to implement using something like tf.reduce_sum(labels*features)/tf.reduce_sum(labels) for the mean for example.

Comment: tf.reduce_sum(labels*features)/tf.reduce_sum(labels) is going to produce a single average of all features, weighted by labels. This is quite different from what is requested in the question.

Comment: Not sure why you think its is so different I must misunderstand the question...Maybe you are looking for tf.nn.embeddings_lookup() ?

Comment: You should specify exactly what you want your question is too vague.